# apt-get update fails with custom repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

In my /etc/apt/sources.list I have an entry

```
deb https://www.myserver.tld/download/Linux/Ubuntu/ bionic main
```

The path on this server is valid, the packages can be found in

https://www.myserver.tld/download/Linux/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/

and the packages-file is located in

https://www.myserver.tld/download/Linux/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

Nevertheless when I do an "apt-get update" it complains with

```
"http://www.myserver.tld/download/Linux/Ubuntu bionic Release" does not contain a release file
```

So...what is wrong here? What release-file is meant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a Release file in that main folder, similar to other apt repositories - http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/Release

Comment: OK, how can I generate this Release-file on server side? Any way to use dpkg-scanpackages for this?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to generate a Release file on your server but [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403485/how-to-generate-the-release-file-on-a-local-package-repository) looks to be the closest match to what you're trying to do.